# TextView Scrolling Issue

Tags: android, scroll, textview

Hii

I was coding for an application that shows the list of running process and i was using TextView to display the running process in screen.
I was trying 2 different method for displaying the TextView.
In one method i was declearing the TextView in the code itself

```
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
this.setContentView(tv);
```

In the second method i was declearing the layout in the main.xml file

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
TextView tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.RunApp);
```

For both the methods i am using the setMovementMethod for having the scroll movement for my TextView

```
tv.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

The program is running fine in the emulator.But if i am using the second method then the scrolling is not happening if i am running the application in my mobile. In the emulator its working fine. Why is it behaving differently in my Android 2.1 Samsung Galaxy S??
Why the scrolling not happening in the second method??. Scrolling is happening in the first method without any issues in my mobile.

This is my code..

```
public class listRunningApps extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.main);
    //TextView tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.RunApp);

    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    this.setContentView(tv);

    tv.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod()); 

    ActivityManager actvityManager = (ActivityManager)
               this.getSystemService( ACTIVITY_SERVICE );
    List<RunningAppProcessInfo> procInfos = actvityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();

    for(int j=0; j < 2; j++) 
/*I have done iteration 2 times so that we have a long process list 
    sufficeint enough for scrolling*/
        {
        for(int i = 0; i < procInfos.size(); i++)
            {
                tv.setText(tv.getText().toString()+procInfos.get(i).processName+
                    " " + String.valueOf(procInfos.get(i).processName.length())+"\n");
            }

    tv.setText(tv.getText().toString()+"----------------------------"+"\n");
        }
     }
}
```

This is my main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/jsttxt"  
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="Testing TextView Scrolling"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/RunApp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30px"
    android:layout_marginRight="30px"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/jsttxt"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

In the first method the scrolling is coming in my mobile without any issue..Can you guys help me why the scrolling is not happening in my mobile in the second method, where as its working properly in my emulator??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why not you are putting your textview in scrollview in your xml layout. try that i think it work

Answer (score 0):

I have modified the main.xml with the scrollview as suggested by ud_an

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/jsttxt"  
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="Testing TextView Scrolling"/>

<ScrollView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/RunApp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30px"
    android:layout_marginRight="30px"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/jsttxt"
    />
</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Now scrolling is working in the second method too.. Thanks ud_an

But why the emulator and my mobile acting indifferently in the previous case where in emulator scrolls and in mobile no scroll???